# modify a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to modify a dictionary. I have a dictionary with integer values and want to replace each value with the fraction of the total of all values, eg.:
`census={a:4, b:1, c:3}; turnIntoFractions(census)`, should then print `{a:0.5, b:0,125 ,c:0,375 }`

I was thinking something like:

```
def turnIntoFractions:
    L=d.keys()
    total=sum(L)
    F=[]
    for count in L:
        f.append(float(count/float(total))
    return F
```

I'm kind of stuck, and it isn't working..

Comment: Please indent your code by 4 spaces to make it more readable

Comment: There are a number of problems with your code. If you want specific help you should say what you mean by "isn't working"

Answer (score 3):

You can use dictionary comprehension.

```
def turnIntoFractions(d):
   total = float(sum(d.values()))
   return {key:(value/total) for key,value in d.items()}
```

Comment: I'd use `total = float(sum(d.values())` and `{key:(value/total) for key, value in d.items()}`

Comment: @jcollado That's definitely more readable. Edited my answer, thanks. Might be also good to point out, that the `float()` is not necessary in python3.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that you are doing the sum of the keys, not the values:

```
total = sum(d.values())
```

Now, you can just modify the dictionary inline, instead of putting it into a new list:

```
for key in d.keys():
    d[key] /= total    # or d[key] = d[key] / total
```

My previous code goes through each key, retrieves the value, then divides by total, and then finally stores it back into `d[key]`.

---

If you want a new dictionary returned, instead of just modifying the existing one, you can just start out with `e = d.copy()`, then use `e` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to edit the dict in place, but your code returns a new object, which is actually better practice.

```
def turnIntoFractions(mydict):
    values=d.values()
    total=float(sum(values))
    result = {}
    for key, val in mydict.items():
        result[key] = val/total
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dictionary comprehension

```
sum = float(sum(census.itervalues()))

newDict = {k : (v / sum) for k,v  in census.iteritems()}
```

for python 2.6:

```
newDict  = dict((k,v /sum) for (k,v) in census.iteritems())
```

Answer (score 0):

The following Python code will modify the dictionary's keys to float values.

```
   def turnIntoFractions(mydict):
      total = sum(mydict.values())
      for key in mydict:
        mydict[key] = float(mydict[key]) / total
```

Answer (score 0):

your code has the right idea, but also a few small mistakes.
here's a working code:

```
def turnIntoFractions(d):
    L=d.values()
    total=sum(L)
    f=[]
    for count in L:
        f.append(float(count/float(total)))
    return f

census={'a':4, 'b':1, 'c':3}

print(turnIntoFractions(census))
```

note that python is case sensitive so f is not the same as F, and also keys that are strings need to be quoted